# Upgrading Rails 3.2 app to Rails 4, Strong Params behaving strange

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, strong-parameters, mass-assignment

I'm in the middle of the process of upgrading a Rails 3.2 app to Rails 4.
I'm working on replacing the `attr_accessible` from the models with Strong Params in controller.
I noticed that the `#permit` method behaves a bit different on the 3.2 I'm upgrading than it should behave in a Rails 4 app. In order to validate my suspicion I created a new Rails 4 app from scratch and tested the same code while getting a different outcome:

**Rails 3.2 app that is currently being upgraded**

```
 [9] pry(main)> x = { attr1: { attr2: "val1", attr3: "val2"}, attr4: "val3", attr5: "val4", attr6: { attr7: "val5"}}
 => {:attr1=>{:attr2=>"val1", :attr3=>"val2"}, :attr4=>"val3", :attr5=>"val4", :attr6=>{:attr7=>"val5"}}
 [10] pry(main)> params = ActionController::Parameters.new x
 => {"attr1"=>{"attr2"=>"val1", "attr3"=>"val2"}, "attr4"=>"val3", "attr5"=>"val4", "attr6"=>{"attr7"=>"val5"}}
 [11] pry(main)> params.require(:attr1)
 => {"attr2"=>"val1", "attr3"=>"val2"}
 [12] pry(main)> params.permit(:attr1)
  ActionController::UnpermittedParameters: found unpermitted parameters: attr1, attr4, attr5, attr6
 [19] pry(main)> params.permit(:attr4)
 ActionController::UnpermittedParameters: found unpermitted parameters: attr1, attr5, attr6
```

**Rails 4 app**

```
 2.2.3 :009 >  x = { attr1: { attr2: "val1", attr3: "val2"}, attr4: "val3", attr5: "val4", attr6: { attr7: "val5"}}
 => {:attr1=>{:attr2=>"val1", :attr3=>"val2"}, :attr4=>"val3", :attr5=>"val4", :attr6=>{:attr7=>"val5"}}
 2.2.3 :012 > params = ActionController::Parameters.new x
 => {"attr1"=>{"attr2"=>"val1", "attr3"=>"val2"}, "attr4"=>"val3", "attr5"=>"val4", "attr6"=>{"attr7"=>"val5"}} 
 2.2.3 :013 > params.require(:attr1)
 => {"attr2"=>"val1", "attr3"=>"val2"} 
 2.2.3 :014 > params.permit(:attr1)
 => {}
 2.2.3 :032 > params.permit(:attr4)
 => {"attr4"=>"val3"}
```

I use the `protected_attributes` gem during the upgrade and I also placed this code in `config/initializers/strong_parameters.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection)
# config.action_controller.always_permitted_parameters =  %w( controller action format )

module ActionController
  class Parameters
    remove_const(:NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS) if (defined?(NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS))

    NEVER_UNPERMITTED_PARAMS = %w( controller action format)
  end
end
```

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to permit all nested parameters, see here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit.

So in your case, for the first attribute you should do

```
params.permit(attr1: [:attr2, :attr2])
```

and likewise for the other parts of your hash.

Comment: Sorry but this has nothing to do with the question I was asking. I know that you should permit nested params as well. My question was regarding the fact that no matter what I try to permit I will get ` ActionController::UnpermittedParameters:`.

Comment: Also if you read my question you should have noticed that I also provided an example where I whitelist `attr4` that doesn't have any nested params yet I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the reason I was getting this error was because I had this setting in my `config/application.rb`

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

Deleting it gave me the ability to permit only the params I wanted.